# Use Informatica to call a stored procedure with return value

Tags: informatica

I need to create a process to purge data from different tables in different schema/server and record the number of records deleted in a log table.
There will be a table containing a list of tables names, schema and number of days to keep the data.

I'm thinking separate mapping for the different servers.
For the same server but different schema, I will dynamically create the call for the stored procedure or function.
It needs to return the number of records deleted and write to the log table.

I'm not sure what's the base approach to do this.
Should i be using a stored procedure or function.
I'm guessing i should be using SQL transformation to execute the sp/function.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just insert into the log table in the stored proc itself? instead of returning the value to informatica and then inserting into a table.

If you are going with the your approach, you can use stored proc transformation in informatica to execute the sp or function. You dont need to have an SQL transformation.